# react native can't connect to android device

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm just start learning react native and I'm trying to use expo,
after I created my app using expo and try to connect it to expo app on android device
I got this error
`Uncaught Error:java.net.socketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /172.28.118.45 (port 19000) from /192.168.1.3 (port 38238) after 10000ms`

I'm using wsl2 on windows and I think the problem could be, there's no bridge between wsl2 ip and windows ip but I couldn't find solution for this issue

Answer (score 0):

This happend me before, but using only react native in WSL (not with expo) and you're right, the WSL cannot reach your android device.
I find some solutions but none of this work for me, you can try it maybe with expo is different.

Check https://localcoder.org/running-react-native-in-wsl-with-the-emulator-running-directly-in-windows